# Adding a relationship in Ecto (Phoenix 1.3)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am trying to establish a one-to-many relationship.  A user can create any number of posts.  Phoenix 1.3, Ecto 2.2.1

```
#migrations
defmodule MyApp.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsersPosts do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:users) do
      add :email, :string, null: false
      add :handle, :string, null: false
      add :password_hash, :string, null: false

      timestamps
    end
  end
...
  def change do
    create table(:posts) do
      add :title, :string
      add :users_id, references(:users, on_delete: :delete_all)
      add :content, :text

      timestamps()
    end
    create index(:posts, [:users_id])

  end
end
```

---

```
#models
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:id, :email, :handle]}

  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :handle, :string
    field :password_hash, :string

    has_many :posts, MyApp.Post
    timestamps
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.Post do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :string
    belongs_to :users, MyApp.User

    timestamps()
  end
end
```

---

```
#seeds.exs
MyApp.User.changeset(%MyApp.User{}, %{
  email: "me@myapp.com",
  handle: "me",
  password_hash: Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("me")})
|> MyApp.Repo.insert!

user = MyApp.Repo.get_by(MyApp.User, email: "me@myapp.com")
MyApp.Post.changeset(%MyApp.Post{}, %{
    title: "title",
    content: "content",
    users_id: user.id
})
|> MyApp.Repo.insert!
```

When I run the migrations and seed, I see the following when I query the post:

```
%MyApp.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "resources">,
  content: "content", title: "title",
  users: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :users is not loaded>,
  users_id: nil}
```

Even though I was successfully able to fetch the user id, I was unable to insert it into the `users_id` field.  I am sure there is something simple that I am missing, what do I have to do to insert these relationships?

Answer (score 3):

First of all - foreign key like `user_id` should be named exactly this way, not `users_id` like you do have. 
Also please check how your `MyApp.Post.changeset` looks like. Propably you should add this new parameter in the list of `optional` allowed parameters. Otherwise it will be ignored by this function.

Comment: Can you include an example of how to include this parameter in the `optional` list?

Comment: Sure, what you put into `cast` is your optional list: https://github.com/learnphoenixtv/blog/blob/master/lib/blog/post.ex#L16. I preffer the way it was in Phoenix 1.2, where you use module attributes to specify the `optional` and `required` parameters and then you use these lists respectively in `cast` and `validate_required`.